# Kubernetes: Support for Prometheus Native Histograms

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I see Prometheus has support for a new type of Histogram called [Native Histograms](https://promcon.io/2022-munich/talks/native-histograms-in-prometheus/).

I have been trying to find out if there is support for these in Kubernetes. i.e. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/instrumentation/metrics/ - can I configure Kubernetes somehow to expose Native Histograms and scrape them from Prometheus?

Does anyone know if this is possible?